# How to Download a PDF file from Azure in ASP.NET MVC via Save Dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I have a file stored on Azure storage that I need to download from ASP.NET MVC controller. The code below actually works fine.

```
string fullPath =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pdfStorage"].ToString() + fileName ;
Response.Redirect(fullPath);
```

However, the PDF opens in the same page. I want the file to be downloaded via a Save dialog box, so the user stays on the same page. Before moving to Azure, I could write

```
return File(fullPath, "application/pdf", file);
```

But with Azure that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the file and then push to the web browser so the user will be able to save.

```
var fileContent = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(fullPath); //byte[]

return File(fileContent, "application/pdf", "my_file.pdf");
```

This particular [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835(v=vs.98).aspx) takes a byte array, a content type and a destination file name.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean `Azure Blob Storage` when you say `Azure Storage`, there are two other ways without actually downloading the file from storage to your web server and both of them involve setting [`Content-Disposition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contentdisposition.aspx) property on your blob.

1. If you want the **file to always download** when accessed via a URL, you can set blob's content-disposition property.

   ```
   var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
   var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
   var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container-name");
   var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("somefile.pdf");
   blob.FetchAttributes();
   blob.Properties.ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"somefile.pdf\"";
   blob.SetProperties();
   ```
2. However if you want the **file to be downloaded sometimes and displayed in the browser other times**, you can create a shared access signature and override the content-disposition property in the SAS and use that SAS URL for downloading.

   ```
       var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
       var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
       var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container-name");
       var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("somefile.pdf");
       var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
       {
           Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
           SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
       }, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
       {
           ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"somefile.pdf\"",
       });
       var downloadUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sasToken);//This URL will always do force download.
   ```